# Failing to deliver Azure NotificationHub push messages to (Android) devices from .NET console app

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have configured a .NET App Service using the "Quick Start" instructions in the newer Azure Portal to publish an app service to use as my mobile back end. I have also configured a notification hub for it and am able to send push notifications from a Xamarin.Forms Android app via the Azure mobile back end endpoint. I can also receive the push notification on a registered Android device.

I need to be able to send push notifications to registered devices from a C# console application but no matter what I try, the push messages are not delivered.

I am using the following code to attempt to send push messages. When I run it, the execution ends on...

```
 var result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams);
```

...and console app terminates without waiting for the response and the push notification is never delivered to the registered device.

```
public async void PushSmartAlerts()
{
    string notificationHubName = "DevXXXXNotificationHub";
    string notificationHubConnection = "Endpoint=sb://devXXXXXnotificationhubnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=SnXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9N8=";
    hub = NotificationHubClient .CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName);
    Dictionary<string, string> templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    templateParams["messageParam"] = "Hello";
        var result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong or if I am going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. There was nothing wrong with the way I was using the NotificationHubClient to create and send the notification. The reason it was not working is that Console applications do not support `await` in the Main method so execution was ending before the push notification could be sent. By changing the code to the following, the push notification was sent and delivered.

```
   string notificationHubName = "xxxxxxx";
    string notificationHubConnection = "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxx";
     hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName, true);
    Dictionary<string, string> notification = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"messageParam", "It works. Tap to view."}
    };
    var task = hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(notification);
    task.Wait();
```